# The localhost page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request-Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.3, linux-mint

I am recently installed linux mint.I am tried to create a project via composer.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test
```

Everything was fine. but when i hit the url **http://localhost/test/public/** i get an error like

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Why this error?.please help me.

Comment: did you set the write permission for bootstrap/cache and storage/ ?

Comment: @thanks Ravisha Hesh-now it's working